# how to change the default compiler on mac osx 10.8.2

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-construction

I am using mac osx 10.8.2 and Xcode v4.6 with llvm-gcc (i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2), when I tried to install a software I realised that this old software is not compatible with this new compiler, so I installed the old version gcc-4.2 (i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1) in /usr/local/bin, whereas llvm-gcc is in /usr/bin, but I also see gcc-4.2 in /usr/bin together with llvm-gcc. When I tried to install the software again I still got the same errors. I think  I need to change the default to gcc-4.2. After searching online i have tried many methods suggested but still without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks